# If I can't use WebRTC, what can I use right now for live streaming video

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, webrtc, rtmp

I'm working on a web app in node.js to allow clients to view a live streaming video via a unique url that another client will broadcast from their webcam, i.e., http://myapp.com/thevideo

I understand that webRTC is still not supported in enough browsers to be useful.
I would also like to save this the video stream to be viewed later within the app.

Things get somewhat confusing as I try to narrow down a solution to make this work.
I would like to get some recommendations on proven solutions out there to make this work on desktop and mobile? Any hints would be great.

Comment: this is a VERY big topic. There is no one size fits all solution. What are your requirements? How many streams? how may viewers per stream? what latency is desired? What quality is desired? Mobile? What platforms should it be playable on? Do you need it to work over proxies? How much server resources do you have available?

Comment: @szatmary do you know of any decent node projects for doing this as a jump off point?

Comment: @szatmary I don't have the answer to all of those questions. I just need something to get going, but the solution should be able to scale. I would say I need a solution that has an option to work on mobile. Quality could be non-HD, but decent. It should be playable on the most popular desktop browsers, Chrome, IE, FF, Safari, and mobile Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a quick suggestion based on the limited details. I would use ffmpeg to encode to HLS. This format will playback natively on iOS and safari on Mac. For all other platforms, either provide an rtmp stream with a flash front end, or use jw player 6 commercial version that can play HLS. Or use a wowza server to handle this all for you.